# Producing SEO friendly URL in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a PHP function that converts a URL to an SEO friendly URL:

```
function seo_url($input){
     $input = str_replace(array("'", "-"), "", $input); //remove single quote and dash
     $input = mb_convert_case($input, MB_CASE_LOWER, "UTF-8"); //convert to lowercase
     $input = preg_replace("#[^a-zA-Z0-9]+#", "-", $input); //replace everything non an with dashes
     $input = preg_replace("#(-){2,}#", "$1", $input); //replace multiple dashes with one
     $input = trim($input, "-"); //trim dashes from beginning and end of string if any
     return $input;
}
```

I know it's pointless for SEO to do this to a URL in javascript, but for the sake of consistency I want URL's to appear the same in my application. Does anyone have the function  handy in javascript? `:]`

Answer (score 27):

Getting pieces of different solutions together, please consider this alternative code, a one-liner:

```
function toSeoUrl(url) {
    return url.toString()               // Convert to string
        .normalize('NFD')               // Change diacritics
        .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g,'') // Remove illegal characters
        .replace(/\s+/g,'-')            // Change whitespace to dashes
        .toLowerCase()                  // Change to lowercase
        .replace(/&/g,'-and-')          // Replace ampersand
        .replace(/[^a-z0-9\-]/g,'')     // Remove anything that is not a letter, number or dash
        .replace(/-+/g,'-')             // Remove duplicate dashes
        .replace(/^-*/,'')              // Remove starting dashes
        .replace(/-*$/,'');             // Remove trailing dashes
}
```

Comment: Nice snippet, thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Take a look at this Javascript module (I'm the author), which works in browser and server/nodejs:
[SpeakingURL](https://github.com/pid/speakingurl)

Comment: Simple - easy to use, works without problems. Thank you! :)

Comment: @pid Link is dead

Comment: Here's a working link to the library https://github.com/pid/speakingurl

Answer (score 5):

```js
var url ="Evanston, IN 47531, USA pizza food & wine & music";

document.write(ToSeoUrl(url));
  
function ToSeoUrl(url) {
        
  // make the url lowercase         
  var encodedUrl = url.toString().toLowerCase(); 

  // replace & with and           
  encodedUrl = encodedUrl.split(/\&+/).join("-and-")

  // remove invalid characters 
  encodedUrl = encodedUrl.split(/[^a-z0-9]/).join("-");       

  // remove duplicates 
  encodedUrl = encodedUrl.split(/-+/).join("-");

  // trim leading & trailing characters 
  encodedUrl = encodedUrl.trim('-'); 

  return encodedUrl; 
}
```

Comment: Note

```encodedUrl = encodedUrl.trim('-'); ```

Will not remove `-` from the beginning/end of the string as `.trim()` does not has any parameters.

Comment: You sir, are a life saver